# Keeping javascript minified inside the database

Tags: javascript, php

I have written a script that is placed on different websites. It puts some html/css there. I have also written a website that enables to configure this html/css for each website.

That's why the script has to load html/css from the database. And that's why I have to keep javascript inside the database, and then use some `eval` to fire it from the script.

My question is - how can I keep something like this minified in the database, and then display it nicely formatted in some wysiwyg editor?

Sample text:

```
var el = document.createElement('body');
el.innerHTML = 'foobar';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(el);
```

This is what I want to get in my wysiwyg editor, but in DB I want this:

```
var el = document.createElement('body');el.innerHTML = 'foobar';document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(el);
```

So I have to somehow convert between those two.

Comment: There are several soundness problem with your question (first being why are you using eval and storing JS into database). Also its impossible to restore minified script into original... Converting JS into minified code is a lossy conversion. Descriptive names like `functionUpdatesStuff` will become `x` or other one letter symbols.

Comment: You should keep both files on the server, but when the WYSIWYG gets submitted (display regular js file here), replace the minified JS with a new version, compiled from the just saved normal JS.

Comment: Yes I know it's a bad design, everyone keeps saying that. But what's a different way? Storing a lot of files for each user on the server? I'd still have to use eval.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a regular expressions to do that (if you just want to place all code at the single line into the DB):

To store from the editor to the database do

```
var codeToDB = WYSIWYG_value.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"");
```

To restore from the database

```
var codeToWYSIWYG = codeFromDB.replace(/;/g,";\n")
```